Python Jupyter Notebook kernel in VSCode not defaulting to prior settings after attempting to run a prior version of Python
Background: I was getting comfortable running without a glitch Jupyter Notebooks in VSC. However, I tried to run an old NB, and it didn't run due to some deprecated commands in the code. So I tried using an older version of Python. All this within VSC. It didn't recognize install numpy as np, which I don't know if it had to do with some python environment issues. So I let it go.
Now, whenever I try to run a previously functioning Jupyter NB with my most updated version of Python (3.11), I have to point to it by going to command palette and selecting it. Further, it doesn't seem to settle (the kernel name keeps on spinning), and as soon as I run the first cell, I get this error:
[][1
However, if I start a terminal and type pip3 install ipykernel, I get that the requirements are already satisfied.
Clearly my experiment with an old version of Python with NB's altered a few settings. It didn't affect .py files - just NB's.
How can I return to the baseline settings?

It is recommended to install packages in a virtual environment (venv) instead.
It may be convenient to create a new environment with vscode by clicking "Python 3.x" or "Select Kernel" located in the top right corner, and follow the instructions there.
Alternative, you may create venv with commands:

First, confirm the Python version you have with py, which is the Python launcher on Windows.
py --list


To create a venv called example-venv with Python 3.11 in the working directory
py -3.11 -m venv example-venv


Activate the environment
. .\example-venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1


Install required packages
python -m pip install jupyterlab


To configure vscode with the venv, open the Command Palette (F1 / Ctrl+Shift+P), "Python: Select Interpreter", "Enter interpreter path..", "Find...", locate Scripts\python.exe inside the venv path. (In this example, example-venv\Scripts\python.exe)

Now, by clicking "Python 3.x" or "Select Kernel" located in the top right corner of notebooks, the venv should be listed. Select it and the cell should be able to run.



PS. The terminal is powershell in Windows Terminal.

Thank you. I've been playing with it, but at this point I have no virtual environments, and would like to return to being able to play notebooks.
